# Framework to push notification to mobile devices (i.e.Android, Apple IPhone) from a web application

Tags: java, android, web-applications, cloud

I have been given a requirement to write a web application that has the capability of pushing notifications (apart from other things) to subscribed uses who are using mobile devices.

I have some plans to write my own implementation on Java. But before I do that, does anyone know a good Java based framework out there to do this job without writing code from scratch.

Main purpose is to push notifications to Android devices from the web application to start with.

All ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find all you want here : [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

As far as completely out of the box solution, there are none available(to my knowledge). However, Google Cloud Messaging(http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) is about as close as you will get to an out of the box solution.

The client-side implementation is rather simple, you can pretty much just copy and paste sample code from the developer. The server side implementation is where the majority of time will be spent, from experience; however, I worked with it in its infancy, so there very well may be a plug and play 3rd party library available for whatever web framework you are using, now that it has been out a fair bit of time.